# Why is “eine Sicherung ziehen” sometimes used for “to make a backup”?

Tags: etymology, technical-terminology

I sometimes read *Sicherung ziehen* and it would be interesting to know where this expression comes from.

Context example:

> Wenn die Datenbank sehr groß ist, kannst Du auch tagsüber eine vollständige **Sicherung ziehen** und die Datenbank ...

Comment: Probably inspired by the (I would say) older "eine Kopie ziehen" which exists in English as well "pull a copy"

Comment: @Emanuel: Yes; I would also speak of a _Sicherungskopie_ (or _Sicherheitskopie_), not just of a _Sicherung_. But people are lazy, so the shortened word is not surprising. ;-)

Comment: Well "Sicherung ziehen" is valid but will have the opposite effect: pull the circuit breaker 

Comment: "ziehen" is sometimes used as a synonym for "to download", "to get" or "to fetch". It is usual to say "Du kannst dir die Daten aus dem Internet _ziehen_." when "You can download the data from the internet." is meant. This seems analogous to "to make a backup" to me.

Comment: this is not backed up by facts: there was a tendency (back in the edv-days (_elektronische Datenverarbeitung_, IT nowadays)) to use sloppy, sometimes weirdly german expressions. I always related that to the fact that back in the days the EDV-abteilung often consisted of rather isolated men with a somewhat technical background (say engineers), some expressions survived

Comment: @AnderM.Morris: You might want to turn that into an answer.

Comment: @gpinkas: You may ask in German here, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Ausdruck ist eine Kurzform von *eine Sicherungskopie ziehen*, und das sehe ich wiederum als Spezialfall von *eine Kopie ziehen*. Dieser Ausdruck wurde auch schon im analogen Zeitalter verwendet im Sinne von *eine Vervielfältigung anfertigen*. Er stammt ursprünglich aus der Filmindustrie. [Wikipedia schreibt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filmkopie#Kontaktkopie):

> Für eine Kontaktkopie wird das zu kopierende Filmmaterial fest auf das unbelichtete Filmmaterial (Kopierfilm) gepresst (Emulsion auf Emulsion), wobei man mit Positionierorganen für die Führung sorgt. Die derart in Kontakt gebrachten Filmstreifen werden mit hoher kontinuierlicher Geschwindigkeit über einen Lichtspalt gezogen. Daher spricht man auch vom „Ziehen“ einer Kopie.

Für die Verwendung in dieser Bedeutung findet man einige Belege bei [Google Books](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22kopie+ziehen%22&hl=de&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1950%2Ccd_max%3A31.12.1990&tbm=bks). Interessant sind dabei insbesondere

> Danach wurden U-matic-masters versandt, von denen sich Interessenten selbst eine VHS-Kopie ziehen konnten.  <sup>Publikation von 1986, [Quelle](https://books.google.de/books?id=GgkdAQAAMAAJ&q=%22kopie+ziehen%22&dq=%22kopie+ziehen%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCGoVChMIiaXc14arxwIVx1wUCh3QZwn6)</sup>

sowie im SPIEGEL-Archiv

> Weil der Amateurfilm nicht in die Übertragungsanlage im Moskauer NBC-Studio paßte, wurde er über die Anlage von ARD-Korrespondent Lutz Lehmann nach Hamburg überspielt, dort auf US-Spur umkopiert und dann weiter nach New York gesendet. Dafür konnte sich der NDR eine eigene Kopie ziehen.  <sup>Publikation von 1987, [Quelle](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-13523727.html)</sup>
>
> Widmaier kritisiert nun, daß das Gericht sich nicht nachträglich eine Videokopie des Films besorgt ... habe. ... Widmaier selber hat sich bei Sat 1 für 1049 Mark eine Kopie ziehen lassen. <sup>Publikation von 1989, [Quelle](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-13523727.html)</sup>
>
> Nahezu alle renommierten Opernhäuser nehmen heute ihre Premieren zwecks interner Begutachtung selbst auf, da läßt sich leicht eine Kopie ziehen.  <sup>Publikation von 1988, [Quelle](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-13529031.html)</sup>

weil es hier jeweils schon um eine übertragene Verwendung der Phrase geht, bei der ziemlich sicher das wortgebende Vervielfältigungsverfahren nicht angewendet wurde. Im letzten Beispiel handelt es sich offenbar auch nicht mehr um Filme, sondern um reine Tonaufnahmen.

Nachdem die Wendung bis Ende der 80er also schon auf jegliche Vervielfältigung von Audio- und Videoaufnahmen angewendet werden konnte, erscheint es mir durchaus plausibel, dass sie bald darauf den Sprung in die Internet- und IT-Sprache gefunden hat - allzumal Film- und Tondokumente dort ja bald zu den beliebtesten Kopierdokumenten gehörten.

Als Randbemerkung möchte ich noch darauf hinweisen, dass das verwandte Hauptwort *Abzug* schon sehr viel länger die Bedeutung der Kopie in sich trägt, denn auch von Druckstöcken wurde das Papier *abgezogen*. Entsprechend findet man auch in Grimms Wörterbuch unter den [Erläuterungen zu *Abzug*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=abzug):

> der abzug ... des druckbogens, des kupferstichs

Answer (score 2):

My former comment:

"ziehen" is sometimes used as a synonym for "to download", "to get" or "to fetch". It is usual to say "Du kannst dir die Daten aus dem Internet ziehen." when "You can download the data from the internet." is meant. This seems analogous to "to make a backup" to me.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the expression *ZIEHEN*  derieves from *DRAG* in this case.

With the first graphical systems *drag&drop* became an expression. That was translated by MS as "hinüberziehen" (from one location to the other). Thus *ZIEHEN* became a synonym for *KOPIEREN*.

Also *ziehen* is slang term for *obtain* (maybe there's a better verb?). Coming from old vending machines where you hat to *PULL* a drawer in which your cigarettes or bubblegum laid.
*Ich geh mal eben ne Schachtel Kippen ziehen*.

There's another one ;-)
*Ziehen* is slang term for (mostly) minor thefts, too. It's mostly used reflexive or with the preposition *ab* as in *abziehen*.
*Gestern nacht wollten mich 3 Jungs **abziehen**.*
*Lisa **zieht sich** immer ne Packung Kaugummi, wenn die Kassiererin nicht guckt.*
*Tom **zieht** Sascha immer das Geld für's Mittagessen **ab**.*

Comment: It should be noted that _abziehen_ has many different meanings, most of them not being slang. The last sentence also could be understood in [another way (to calculate a difference)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abziehen#Bedeutung14a), depending on the context.